# Async/await inside for...of vs. map

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I'm trying to figure out why promises seem to work differently inside of `for...of` vs. `map()`.

`data` is an array of objects of the form `{app: MY_APP, link: MY_LINK}`. I'm trying to convert it to the form `{app: MY_APP, status: true OR false}}`. The function `checkLink()` is async because it uses `node-fetch` and basically returns whether the given link is 200. Using `for...of`, I get the desired object:

```
let objToSend = [];
for (obj of data) {
  objToSend.push({ app: obj.app, status: await checkLink(obj.link) });
}

// returns [{app: MY_APP, status: true}, ...]
```

But using `map`, as follows, I get an array of pending promises instead. Any help would be appreciated:

```
let objToSend = data.map(async obj => {
  return {
    app: obj.app,
    status: await checkLink(obj.link)
  };
});

// returns [ Promise { <pending> }, ...]
```

I also tried doing `Promise.all(objToSend)` after the `map` code, but it instead returns `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Your callback returns a promise, so unsurprisingly it maps to promises.

Comment: One way to think about this is that the `for` loop is a loop inside a single function. That single function returns a single promise. A `map()` is many function inside a loop. Each function returns a promise so you end up with an array of promises.

Comment: This tweet might help you. https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/1264284487799595008?s=20

Answer (score 4):

I'll leave the explanation up to the other answers, but just want to point out that there is also a performance difference.

Your first solution waits on every iteration for the promise to resolve, only calling `checkLink` if the previous one has resolved. This is a sequential solution.

```
check link1 => wait => check link2 => wait => check link3 => wait
```

The second solution iterates over every element and sends out requests, without waiting for promises to resolve; For this reason, an array of promises is returned. If you wait for all promises to be resolved you find this solution is a lot faster, since the requests are sent out in parallel.

```
check link1 => check link2 => check link3 => wait for all
```

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function checkLink(link) {
  await sleep(Math.random() * 1000 + 500); // sleep between 500 and 1500 ms
  console.log(link);
  return `status #${link}`;
}

(async function () {
  const data = new Array(5).fill().map((_, index) => ({ app: "app", link: index }));
  let objToSend;
  
  console.log("solution #1");
  objToSend = [];
  for (let obj of data) {
    objToSend.push({ app: obj.app, status: await checkLink(obj.link) });
  }
  console.log(objToSend);

  console.log("==============================================");
  
  console.log("solution #2");
  objToSend = await Promise.all(data.map(async obj => {
    return {
      app: obj.app,
      status: await checkLink(obj.link)
    };
  }));
  console.log(objToSend);
})();
```

In the snippet, the first solution takes `500/1500 * 5 = 2500/7500` between 2500 and 7500 ms, while the second solution takes between 500 and 1500 ms (depending on the slowest value to resolve).

Answer (score 2):

[Async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) always [returns Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value). In your map function, as the callback returns promises, an array of promises is being created.

To convert it to your format, use it with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
(async()=>{
    let objToSend = await Promise.all(data.map(async obj => {
        return {
            app: obj.app,
            status: await checkLink(obj.link)
        };
    }));
    console.log(objToSend) //[{app: MY_APP, status: true}, ...]
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `await` always halts the execution of the `async function` it is in, it doesn't work differently in both cases. In the later example however, you do call some `async function`s, and those calls will evaluate to promises, whereas in your first example, all those `await`s are in the same `async function`.

> I also tried doing `Promise.all(objToSend)` after the map code, but it instead returns `Promise { <pending> }`

Yup, `await` that and you get an array of results.

Comment: But I'd have to `await` the result of the first example too then no?

Comment: @mbj sure, whenever you want to use the result of an `async function` call, you have to `await` that somewhen ... and that `awaut` then has to be inside an `async function` itself.

Comment: Right but in the for loop case I don't have to resolve any promises. I understand that it's one promise (vs. many), but I don't understand why I don't have to resolve it.

Comment: For sure you have to. That `for` loop has to be inside of an `async function` too, and calling that results in a promise.

Comment: So you're saying there should be a line like `await objToSend` in the first case?